# Gamification with Flutter for Web

Tags: flutter

I need to add gamification to a project I am working on, The idea is to motivate people to use the app, and with the sense of competition among peers, I expect the users to try and earn more points by doing stuff that serves my business as well.

Currently, I have a web app running and I understand that Flutter for Web might not be the go-to option for most developers, I still need to solve this problem in Flutter.

I am fairly new to Flutter so I am not aware of the commonly used libraries etc. My previous experience is with the MERN stack mainly. I am looking for some recommendations regarding how to proceed with this,

1. Some guidelines/tutorials to follow
2. What are the most commonly used packages/libraries for gamification

I'm thinking of something similar to commonly used apps like DuoLingo that motivates people to learn a language with points, levels, leaderboards etc.

Any suggestions or guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are you looking for Free or Paid?

Answer (score 2):

You should visit [Flutter Gems](https://fluttergems.dev/) here you can see all packages and their popularity and visually you can see categories and about all packages
There is special section for Game Development and
Games & Rewards where you can find all package for gamifying

for learning you can visit this playlist but this is one year old but still worthy if you are begnner in flutter https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IfUjHNODRoM&list=PL6yRaaP0WPkVtoeNIGqILtRAgd3h2CNpT&ab_channel=VandadNahavandipoor